# Unit of measure in the OLS regression

Tags: regression, least-squares

Suppose I estimate by OLS the following linear model
$$
Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_i+U_i
$$
where $Y_i$ denotes the weight of individual  $i$ (in pounds), and $X_i$ denotes the height of individual $i$ (in inches).

Let $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ be the OLS estimates. Let $R^2$ be the R-squared from the regression . Let $SER$ be the Root Mean Square Error.

**Question:** Suppose that instead of measuring weight and height in pounds and inches, the variables are measured in centimeters and kilograms. What are the regression estimates (coefficients, $R^2$, and SER) from this new centimeter-kilogram regression?
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{1 Pound = 0.453 Kilogram}\\
& \text{1 Inch= 2.54 Centimeter}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Thoughts:** I found similar questions in this forum (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154845/how-will-changing-the-units-of-explanatory-variables-affect-a-regression-model) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311198/showing-that-the-ols-estimator-is-scale-equivariant)) but I'm unable to clear up my mind on how to proceed.

**(A)** With regards to the coefficients, I would suggest to proceed by noticing that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i+U_i & \Leftrightarrow Y_i*0.453=0.453*\beta_0+0.453*\beta_1X_i+0.453*U_i,\\
& \Leftrightarrow Y_i*0.453=0.453*\beta_0+\frac{0.453}{2.54 }*\beta_1(X_i*2.54)+0.453*U_i
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, $\hat{\beta}^{new}_0=0.453*\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}^{new}_1=\frac{0.453}{2.54 }*\hat{\beta}_1$

**(B)** $R^2$ does not change because it has no unit of measure.

**(C)** Let $\hat{U}_i=Y_i-\hat{\beta}_0-\hat{\beta}_1X_i$ and $SER=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{U}_i^2}$. Note that
$$
\hat{U}^{new}_i=Y_i^{new}-\hat{Y}^{new}_i=0.453 *Y_i-\Big[\frac{0.453}{2.54 }*\hat{\beta}_1(X_i*2.54)+0.453\hat{\beta}_0\Big]=0.453* \hat{U}_i
$$
Hence,
$$
SER^{new}=0.453*SER
$$

Are A,B,C  correct?

Comment: Yes, A, B, and C are correct. The coefficients change according to rescaling, R-squared stays the same and the residuals are rescaled with the DV.